# Creating windows forms using OOP technique

Tags: .net, winforms, oop, layer

I need to create 5 similar windows forms with a little bit of changes on each of them. One may have a couple of extra text boxes, other may have less fields. The datatables would be separate but the functionality would be the same. I'll create a dataset with all the relevant TableAdopters in it. Then I'll have another layer of "Business Logic" to fill up the data in the tables. What would be the right approach  for creating forms using "object oriented" technique and how can I implement this?

Comment: You could create custom controls that with with a base class having all the common things and then inherit it as you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Steven says you should really look at composition over inheritance, so make smaller controls which do exactly what you need then just add a few of them into each form. However if you are really set on inheriting you can do so with Winforms, I am pretty sure there is a wizard which even lets you inherit from an existing form.

OOP is different depending on who you talk to, if its someone from a C++ background then they will no doubt say polymorphism and inheritance in the context of oo, however if you talk to people from Java and .net about OO they will probably focus more on encapsulation and composition.

Inheritance still has its place, just most problems can be solved easier and better via composition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Taking a concrete example, suppose I need to create a form "Form A" with 10 text boxes and a grid control containing 5 columns and also to create another form "Form B" with 12 text boxes, having 10 same as in the "From A" and a also grid control with 4 columns in it as well. How would  I implement this using "Composition over inheritance"

Comment: You would create a usercontrol holding 10 textboxes and a usercontrol holding 12 textboxes (or you could make one with 10 and inherit a new control adding 2 more) Then you would add that to your forms, so the behavior of your form a composition of the seperate user controls, rather than inheritance. This way if you need to change the 10 textboxes to 9 for one form, you can just make a new usercontrol with 9 and add that to the given form rather than HAVING to change EVERY form when using direct inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer [Composition over Inheritence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).